# How can i get a url param for an updateview in django?

Tags: python, django, url

url:

```
`path('my-domains/<str:domain_name>/dns-settings', login_required(DNSSettingsUpdateView.as_view()), name='dns_settings')`
```

I want to get str:domain_name to use in my updateview:

```
class DNSSettingsUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Domain
    form_class = NsRecordModelForm
    template_name = "engine/dns_settings.html"

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return Domain.objects.get(name=[would insert it here])

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("my-domains")
```

How can I do this? can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the url parameters through **`self.kwargs`**, which is a dictionary that maps parameters names on to their values, so:

```
class DNSSettingsUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Domain
    form_class = NsRecordModelForm
    template_name = "engine/dns_settings.html"

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return Domain.objects.get(name=self.kwargs['domain_name'])

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("my-domains")
```